# Unable to access module from Default.aspx page, but can access it from Default.aspx.vb

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I created a vb.net Module that outputs strings, based on some configurations in the web.config file. I can call and use the Module functions from methods and functions within the Default.aspx.vb page, but when I try to call the modules from Default.aspx like so:

```
<a href="<% ModuleName.GetHref() %>"><% ModuleName.GetLinkName() %></a>
```

I get

> Error  12  'ModuleName' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

The module is declared like so:

```
Public Module ModuleName
```

and all of the functions within the module are Public:

```
 Public Function GetHref() As String
```

How can I call these functions from within the .aspx page?

Comment: Why don't you use ASP.NET server controls like `HyperLink` and assign it from codebehind via [`NavigateUrl=ModuleName.GetHref()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlink.navigateurl(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`Text=ModuleName.GetLinkName()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlink.text(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Try referencing it with the full namespace `MyApp.ModuleName.GetHref()` for example.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.

It's in the same namespace, but I did try using the fully qualified name, with the namespace first and didn't work>

Tim - good idea, I think that is what I will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use codebehind, i don't think that you can access it directly from aspx. Therefore use the ASP.NET servercontrol `HyperLink` which is rendered as anchor.

Then assign it from codebehind(f.e. `Page_Load`) via [`NavigateUrl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlink.navigateurl(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`Text`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlink.text(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
this.link.NavigateUrl = ModuleName.GetHref();
this.link.Text = ModuleName.GetLinkName();
```

This also has the benefit of compile time safety and is easier to debug.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is what I will have to do. I will mark this as the answer when I am able to (in 4 minutes).